# PHP Client SSL Certificate Authentication

Tags: php, ssl

Please can someone point me in the right direction, i am looking to implement client SSL certificates in the same way as one of our suppliers, the supplier has issued us with a pfx file which takes a password in order to install it, contained within the certificate is our account number in the Organization field.

- How do i generate a single file, revokable new client certificate programmatically through PHP.

Thanks.
Dean.

Comment: The only way I know of is  to use the [Open SSL Extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php)  --  If that doesn't contain the "power" that you need .. You may have to grant PHP `exec` privileges .. Which is a whole other can of worms, that I don't suggest opening ..

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-new.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-sign.php but revocation is not a built-in mechanism, you need to keep track of which certs are valid and optionally set up a CRL endpoint to advertise revocations. You might want to offload all PKI concerns to a dedicated product that can manage the full PKI experience like [Vault's PKI engine](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/pki).